# Running pentaho jobs through activemq JMS

Tags: jms, pentaho, kettle

Is there a way to invoke Pentaho's ETL jobs from ActiveMQ JMS?  I'd like to trigger a job through the messaging system. Has anyone had any experience with this? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JMS consumer comes handy and the corresponding settings (Similar to JMS producer) must be produced at the application. Based on the message reception, the job will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I integrated PDI in a JAX-RS web application with no problem.
Invoking a job execution from JMS should be easy.

Here you can find how to integrate PDI with java: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+-+Java+API+Examples

For webapps you can find tons of material on the net.

Comment: Could you please let me know the steps? My knowledge on webapps is very limited